# Несколько способов создать экземпляр класса в c++. В чем разница?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

```
ifstream in1;
ifstream in2();
ifstream *in3 = new ifstream();
```

В чем разница? Между 2 и 3 еще понятно: один экземпляр хранится на куче, другой в стеке. А что с первым?

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Class
{
public:
    Class() {}
    Class(int a) {}
};
int main()
{
    Class a;
    Class b(4);
    Class c();
    Class *d = new Class();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как-то так выглядит аналогичный код на ассемблере. Компилировал с ключом -O0. Хочу заметить, что Class c(); игнорируется компилятором
Такой вопрос: где хранится класс и указатель this в (1,2) и 4 случае?

Comment: скорее нужно спрашивать что со вторым

Comment: можете пояснить?

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что одно из них не совсем правильное

Comment: дело в том, что все это компилируется

Comment: @suvitruf-says-reinstate-monica, чё за угар? есть вопрос, есть ответ и тут задним числом приезжает доп вопрос

Comment: @goldstar_labs это дополнение от автора вопроса.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Между 1 и 3 еще понятно: один экземпляр хранится на куче. А второй это прототип функции. Объявление с круглыми скобками будет объявлением объекта лишь в том случаи, если в круглых скобках указаны аргументы конструктора. Объект можно создать также с помощью универсального инициализатора.  Объявление
`fstream in2{}`;(фигурные скобки) будет идентично `fstream in2`;

**P.S.** Что касается третьего объекта, то `new ifstream()` это    конструкция `New-expression`, для которой круглые скобки хоть и лишние, но допустимые. Это создания объекта в куче, а не объявление...

Comment: @Alex, согласен, стоит знать международные термины...

Comment: @AlexF, только, скорее не компилятор, а *программист* -)

Answer (score 3):

Исправление ответа, спасибо за комментарий **@ARHovsepyan.**

*Плохо посмотрел ассемблерный вывод прежде чем писать.*

Во втором случае ты создаёшь не экземпляр объекта, а объявляешь функцию которая возвращает ifstream.

В то же время если передать аргументы то это уже будет вызов конструктора
Например пример для std::vector

```
std::vector<int> arr(5, 10);
```

в результате arr=[10,10,10, 10, 10];

---

P.S.

Ещё немного вариантов создания экземпляров:

- например если использовать фигурные скобки будет вызван конструктор принимающий std::initializer_list:

```
std::vector<int> arr{5, 10}; // arr = [5,10]
```

- Так же возможен вариант с размещающим new

```
char data[sizeof(std::vector<int>)];
std::vector<int>* arr = new (data) std::vector<int>();
```

Comment: мне вот интересно тот кто поставил минус прокоментирует за что? Очень любопытно понять что же не так я ответил..

Comment: Приведенный вами пример  не имеет *никакого* отношения  с примером в вопросе.  Вы говорите, что первый и второй эквивалентны, Нет, не правильно. `"Просто в первом ты неявно вызываешь конструктор по умолчанию во втором явно"`. *Нет, это неправильное утверждение*. Если вы утверждаете эквивалентность этих вариантов, то нужно приводить пример объявления вектора  такого:    `std::vector<int> arr()`, что никак у вас не получится. Я, наоборот, удивлен, что кто то    посчитал ваш ответ полезным для данного вопроса. Так что минус от меня.

Comment: `ifstream in2  = ifstream();`      это будет явным вызовом конструктора,  а  не `ifstream in2()` , который вовсе не является объявлением объекта, а является объявлением функции, которая возвращает  объект  `ifstream`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, да, криво прочитал ассемлерный вывод, исправил ответ

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Если уж Вы минусуете то хотя бы поясняйте в чём причина. А то в итоге ответ остался бы ошибочным и вводил в заблуждение.

Comment: *В первом случае ты создаёшь не экземпляр объекта, а указатель на функцию* - тогда уж во втором. И `in2` не указатель, а объявление функции, тела которой нет. Вы можете дописать `in2()`, и все скомпилируется, но не слинкуется.

Comment: @Arenoros, согласен,  лучше указать на то, что считаешь не правильным, только я подумал, что вы сами поймете причину.