# Создание объекта через new и конструктор

Tags: c++, память, new

В чем отличие при создании объекта через конструктор, например вот так:

```
Class1 obj()
```

от создания через new:

```
Class1 *obj = new Class1()
```

VS19 выдавал ворнинг С6262 когда я создавал как в первом примере, при создании указателя этот ворнинг пропал, интересно знать почему так вышло.

Comment: Class1 obj() это не объявление(создание) объекта. Компилятор воспринимает это как прототип функции obj, возвращающий объект Class1, а объявления функции ищется до выполнения программы

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, видимо, автор привëл неверный пример в вопросе, а на самом деле какие-то параметры там были. Иначе бы такого предупреждения не выдало.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095504/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-c-%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0/1095524#1095524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом случае объект располагается на стеке и память для него освободится после выхода из функции, во втором — в динамической памяти и тогда память нужно освобождать вручную с помощью `delete`.

https://ravesli.com/urok-105-stek-i-kucha/

Соответственно, [предупреждение](http://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/code-quality/c6262?view=vs-2019) было из-за того, что объект требовал слишком много стековой памяти.

Comment: В первом случае - увы, это не создание объекта, а объявление функции. Не знаю, как ему удавалось получать такое предупреждение..

Comment: @Harry я, к сожалению, выразился немного неверно, и в данном случае внутри скобок были параметры, это сокращенный вариант вызова конструктора и он может быть похож на вызов функции

Comment: @DLWHI Вопросы надо задавать точно... При неточном ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...